# webpack compile only without build output for check exit code

Tags: webpack

I want to check if my project build is ok or not without get dist output. for example using in gitlab CI which build output(dist directory) is not useful so I just want to know if webpack finished with exit code 0 or not

is there any option for running webpack to make no output?

I'm using typescript compiler in it, but I don't want to use a similar option in `tsc` becouse it will not check if my css or image files are exist or not! I need webpack loaders to full check my code

Thanks in advance

Comment: Create the output and remove it.

Comment: it is so ineffective option I wish some option to make no output to make it faster